# Stack Android Application

Tags: app, android

#### About

Stack is an Android application that lets you browse [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) and other Stack Exchange sites.

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Download / Install

[Download from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.tylerbwong.stack)

#### Code

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/tylerbwong/stack) on GitHub!

The goal of this project is to provide examples for the latest Android libraries and tools. A few noteworthy examples include:

- [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) for asynchronous code
- [Dagger Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) for dependency injection
- [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) for declarative UI code written in Kotlin (Slowly being introduced)
- [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) for local data persistence
- [Markwon](https://github.com/noties/Markwon) for rendering markdown

#### Contact

Created by [Tyler Wong](https://tylerbwong.me)

#### License

Licensed under the [GPL-3.0 License](https://github.com/tylerbwong/stack/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: What's the latest on this app? Downloaded it and it's great, only thing i can see that is wrong is that it doesn't have some of the latest commands you can run in your browser, and you can't @ someone in the comments section. other than that, it's a good app.